How to check for damage in new Z8 with the Z 24-70mm S mounted after a drop?
I have had my Nikon Z8 for 3 months and the backpack fell from a car trunk at a height of 1 meter or approximately 3.3 feet. The backpack is the Samsonite Ecodiver L and has some padding. I had the camera with the Lens attached inside an older (sturdier and more padding) version of the Lowepro Photo Active TLZ 50 camera bag which was inside the Samsonite backpack. The Z8 body and the 24-70mm don't have any external dents or scratches, they are perfect like when unboxed.
After the fall I took many landscape pictures and they were all fine. I also took many many portrait pictures at different apertures f2.8 to f11. All pictures came up perfectly fine. I also recorded a video, changed to HDR overlay, tested different AF modes e.g., AF-S with subject detection, AF-C with 3D etc. all worked.
I also took the picture of my kitten at f2.8 A-priority AF-S subject detection which came up just fine. What else can I check for?


If you only knew some of the things that have happened to some of my cameras and/or lenses over time... If everything still works as well as it did before, I wouldn't worry about it.

Without anymore disassembling of the camera you will probably not be able to find any damage. And since you dropped it inside a bag inside a bag, where at leased one had also padding, there should not much happened. Expensive cameras in this class are normaly build like little tanks and are made for taking some abuse, since they are used as work tools. So dont be too worried.
Just take some photos and videos, use every button and wheel and lever on the camera, also shake it and hear for loose things (attention there might be a normal rattle in the camera, since in older models they used a little steal ball inside some cage to know which orientation the camera has), slowly use the rings on the lens and hear and feel for not so good sounding stuff. See thru the front of the lens and move it slowly, so you could find a possible loosing of a lens (yes i had one in the past :( ), try to rock the lens on the camera mount and check the mount that it is still perfectly plane (weight of some lenses can bend the mount in some extreme situations)
But in the end you cannot fully check everything. There is always a risk left.
I also had a super freaky lens failure, where an inner guide bolt for the inner zoom tubes got loose and jammed the whole lens to garbage.
And if you still unsure: Send it to Nikon for a full check.
(And damn what a nice camera set you have and what a cute cat :) )

Thanks a lot @Horitsu! indeed I think I will send the camera for revision at some later point. I still have 3 years of warranty minus three months and everything seems to be working. I will do couple of focus tests on the edges to see whether it is also good there.

@Horitsu We all know that this question is just an excuse to post a cat picture...

@xenoid thanks hahahah but no, I actually had a hiking trip and the backpack fell off from the trunk while closing the door. The sound of the fall still haunts me in nightmares ...

@SkyWalker Warranty doesn't usually cover damage from "abuse" (such as a drop). Only damage protection policies do that. Some "extended warranties" include damage protection coverage, some don't. Warranties only usually cover defects in parts or workmanship.
